# I want to remove a line from a file using sed

Tags: bash, sed

The line is specicied by the user so I have the number of the line in a variable

```
sed $input 'd' file.txt > file.txt
```

The problem here is that I don't know where and how to put the variable $input. I have tried lot's of combinations and there are all wrong.

I know that if I put a single integer it works but I don't know the way with a variable

Comment: edit your Q to show the things you have tried and error messages you get. Something like `input=3; sed "${input}d" file` should work, as should `input=str ; sed "/${input}/d" file`. Good luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
sed -i "${input}d" file.txt
```

The variable needs to be in braces, use double quotes to prevent matching problems, and use the -i switch to act directly on the file